# Sync Issue in Unix Network Programming

Tags: c++, sockets, unix

I am programming for one of my project "Auction". I put all the conditions for login at both server and client side. My program runs better till some statements but in meanwhile server stops responding.
I research over that by putting print statements and over internet and I found that it is sync problem rather than coding. May be the reason would be different i am not sure.
I also want to mention that when I put "read()" on while condition, things are running as expected. Can anyone please tell me that how to remove/avoid this sync problem (may be something else rather than sync)?
Server.cpp (only some part which is running well)

```
while(((n = read(sockfd,buffer,4096))!=0)&&(l==false)) {
                            if(i==0) cout<<"Username:"<<buffer;
                            if(i==1) { l = true; cout<<"Password:"<<buffer; }
                            i++;
                        }
```

Server.cpp (part before modification that was stucked at i=1)

```
for(i=0; i<2; i++) { cout<<endl<<"i="<<i<<endl;
                            bzero(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));             
                            if((n = read(sockfd,buffer,4096))==0) { cout<<"problem";
                                close(sockfd);
                                FD_CLR(sockfd, &allset);
                                client[i] = -1;
                            } else { cout<<buffer<<i<<endl; if(i==1) {cout<<"copied password"; }
                                            if(i == 0) { cout<<"copied user";} }
```

Comment: Your loop isn't valid. `read()` can return -1 as well, and it isn't guaranteed to fill the buffer. You don't need `bzero()` but you do need to use the result of `read()` when processing the buffer..

Comment: thanks for reply! sorry i did'nt use buffer here just for the simplicity and checking of why it is'nt working. But I want to know "is there anything like sync problem in server while using for loop like above written?"